# Why does FLAG_SECURE blanks screen in some phones and doesn't blur in other phones when app is backgrounded?

Tags: android, security

Below code added on my baseactivity blanks screen when app goes background and makes app data invisible when viewed on recent apps stack in some devices running on OS 8.0,8.1 eg.LG nexus,Samsung Tablet but when I run it on devices below OS 8 like lenovo p2 (Nougat 7.0) or Moto g4 plus, the latest screen is still visible in backgrounded apps stack. Please suggest. I want the app screen to be blank for all devices when backgrounded.

```java
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        super.onPause();

    }
```

When I investigated further, setting FLAG_SECURE is blanking screen only if I set it on oncreate in the previous non-blank devices. But not working when I use above technique. However, I could see through debugger these flags getting set and reset in all devices.